# query on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

A product has to procured if quantity in stock is falls below 10
to be procured is yes or no

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW i(product_line, product_name, vendor_name, quantityinstock, to_be_procured) AS
  SELECT
    productline,
    productname,
    productvendor,
    quantityinstock,
    'N'
  FROM products;

UPDATE i
SET to_be_procured = 'y'
WHERE quantityinstock < 10;
```

getting error like

> virtual column not allowed here update i set to_be_procured='y' where
>   quantityinstock <10

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?  If you want to change the value of a column, it should be a column in the underlying *table*, not a constant in the view definition.

Comment: Your to_be_procured is a column in view with a constant value 'N' which does not exist in your table or not mapped to an actual table column.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the logic inside the view, i.e.:

```
create or replace view I (product_line,
                          product_name,
                          vendor_name,
                          quantityinstock,
                          to_be_procured) as
select productline,
       productname,
       productvendor,
       quantityinstock,
       case when quantityinstock < 10 then 'Y'
            else 'N'
       end to_be_procured
from products;
```

Alternatively, you could just add the logic to the table in a [virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)